# Mysql interesting query

Tags: mysql

I have the next table:

```
+---------+------------+
| firm_id | service_id |
+---------+------------+
|       6 |          2 |
|       6 |          4 |
|      23 |          7 |
|      23 |          6 |
```

I want to get ONLY companies who do **not** have service_id=4 in their service list.

A query of the above table should return only the company with firm_id=23 because firm_id=6 has one record with service_id=4.

I want to make it with one query. Is this possible (without joins)?

Thanks.

P.S. Thanks everyone. User "derobert" suggested very interesting way, what i was looking for.

Comment: WHy without JOIN? Is it homework?

Comment: you should accept his answer if it was what you were looking for...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it several ways. Here is one, with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT firm_id FROM table t1
  WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM table t2 WHERE t1.firm_id = t2.firm_id AND t2.service_id = 4)
```

In MySQL-land it is often better to rewrite as a self-join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT firm_id
  FROM table t1 LEFT JOIN table t2 ON (t1.firm_id = t2.firm_id AND t2.service_id = 4)
  WHERE t2.firm_id IS NULL
```

Finally, here is one way to do it that doesn't involve subqueries or joins (but I expect performs worse than either of the above)

```
SELECT firm_id, CONCAT(',', GROUP_CONCAT(service_id SEPARATOR ','), ',') AS service_ids
  FROM table t1
  GROUP BY firm_id
  HAVING service_ids NOT LIKE '%,4,%'
```

I confess I haven't actually run these; please forgive typos.

Comment: Yhis is cool! i'm thinking what it can't work fast, but very interesting solution, it seems what this is what i need, Thanks.

Comment: Query 1 and 2 by derobert may be the fastest from all you got.

Comment: Although they'll probably both need adjustement: `SELECT DISTINCT firm_id` to only show every firm_id once.

Comment: @user1016265: And if they're not fast, check `EXPLAIN`—and make sure you have appropriate indices.

Comment: @ypercube: Added the missing 'DISTINCT' for the two that need it.

Comment: Thank you very much, derobert.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    firm_id
FROM
    TableX AS t 
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT 
           *
        FROM 
           TableX AS s
        WHERE 
           s.firm_id = t.firm_id
        AND 
           s.service_id = 4
      )
```

or:

```
SELECT 
    firm_id
FROM
    TableX 
GROUP BY 
    firm_id
HAVING
    COUNT(service_id = 4) = 0
```

Comment: +1: Wow, I'd never thought to "abuse" `COUNT` like that before.

Comment: @derobert: It's not going to be terrific performance, probably the worst of all. Except off course yours `GROUP_CONCAT() + NOT LIKE` :)

Comment: Agreed—performance is going to be best with the not exists or join, definitely not with any of the "tricks", all of which probably forbid the use of any index on service_id.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE firm_id NOT IN
  (SELECT DISTINCT firm_id FROM your_table
   WHERE service_id = 4) a
```

As suggested by ypercube (thanks!) you can also try

```
SELECT DISTINCT firm_id, service_id  FROM your_table
WHERE firm_id NOT IN
  (SELECT firm_id FROM your_table
   WHERE service_id = 4) a
```

Comment: It would be better to have `DISTINCT firm_id` in the wrapping query and `SELECT firm_id` in the subquery.

Comment: @ypercube: I tried your way: is it correct? Why is it faster or better? I'm curious...

Comment: `IN (SELECT something ...)` is equivalent to `IN (SELECT DISTINCT something ...)`

Comment: The `SELECT *` you have in the "outer" wrapping query will show multiple rows with same `firm_id`. It's not what teh OP asked for. Otherwise it's a valid query.

Comment: @ypercube: oh, you're right... but I wasn't sure OP needed just firms or full records...